# Angular router link with same component and diffrent params is appending instead of routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I  have a side bar where I am routing. For the first click, I am able to route but from the second click onwards the route are getting appended instead of replacing the old view. I am have removed BrowserAnimationsModule from app.module.ts

side.component.html

```
<aside >
   <sectionclass="sidebar" style="height: auto;">
   <ul *ngFor="let result of test_list| keyvalue let i=index" data- 
  widget="tree">

  <li  *ngFor="let result1 of result.value | keyvalue;let i=index"
    (click)="getSomevalue">


      <ul class="nav submenu " data-widget="tree" (click)="getSomevalue">
      <li *ngFor="let result2 of result.value | keyvalue" 
      >


        <a routerLink="/home/{{result2.value}}" routerLinkActive="on">

     <span>{{result2.key}}</span>
        </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
     </section>
        </aside>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
    path: 'home/:id',

    component: HomeComponent
    }
   ]
  }

  ];

  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
   })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

LayoutComponent.ts

```
     @Component({
   selector: 'app-valid-user-layout',
   template: `
    <app-header></app-header>

  <app-side></app-side>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>

 `       ,
  styles: []
   })
export class ValidUserLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
```

app.component.html

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

http://localhost:4400/home/1  //The first click route is ok

http://localhost:4400/home/2  //Route is appending

Comment: Oftopic: `(click)="true"`???

Comment: What about the code in `HomeComponent`, can the issue be inside there?

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Also, try to remove (click)s from ```side.component.html``` and test again.

Comment: No I am not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/home', result2.value]" routerLinkActive="on">
```